# CoreFoundation Lite on Linux and Android

Tags: linux, macos, android-ndk, core-foundation

I would like to use Apple's CoreFoundation library on linux and android. The source code is available [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.13/), but there is very little documentation on how to build it on Linux.  As far as I could figure out, building is done through a script called BuildCFLite. I grepped for DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

```
./CFUtilities.c:#if DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_MACOSX || DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_EMBEDDED || DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_LINUX || DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_FREEBSD
```

and Linux seems to be supported at first site by setting `-DDEPLOYMENT_TARGET_LINUX`, but some of the compiler flags in that script are not available on linux, so when I try to build I get an error.

Does anybody have experience building the latest version of CoreFoundation for Linux? Also what are the dependencies for building CoreFoundation? Would it be feasible to use it in the Android NDK?

Comment: It's now possible to compile CF-635.15 under Linux using clang 3.0+.  It looks like Apple are fully supporting Linux with CF-Lite now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ported Daniel Côté's Core Foundation Lite (v.299.33) to Android and have hosted the result under Apple's public license on Github.

http://www.mobconverge.com/2011/09/12/core-foundation-on-android/

https://github.com/markshiz/corefoundation-lite-android

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Côté has instructions how to build CoreFoundation Lite on linux:

http://cafeine.crulrg.ulaval.ca/users/dccote/weblog/0514e/CoreFoundation_Lite_on_Linux.html

Looks a bit tricky but possible.